# java.lang.NullPointerException Sun PetStore CatalogFacade

Tags: java, eclipse

in the Sun Java PetStore demo index.jsp file, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception on `cf`

```
CatalogFacade cf = (CatalogFacade)getServletContext().getAttribute("CatalogFacade");
List<Tag> tags=cf.getTagsInChunk(0, 12);  <--- cf is Null
```

I'm using Eclipse and I don't know why CatalogFacade is null or how to debug this.
Any clue greatly appreciated.

Edit:
In the `CatalogFacade` Class which `implements ServletContextListener`

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("CatalogFacade", this);
}
```

Comment: Does your `ServletContext` have an attribute "CatalogFacade"?

Comment: If you are asking if there in an entry in the web.xml, then no.

Answer (score 1):

My first investigation would be to see if `getServletContext().getAttribute("CatalogFacade");` returns a `null`.

If it does, then you've never stored a `CatalogFacade` object in your application. Perhaps look at storing it using `getServletContext().setAttribute("CatalogFacade", cf);`?

That's what I can help you with (with the little info you've provided).

Comment: where would I make that call to setAttribute?  Based on this answer here, I don't have a context but I don't know how to add something to a context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381724/persistenceunit-annotation-wont-create-an-entitymanagefactory-emfnull/4382010#4382010